# String Matching in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been working on a project that takes a spreadsheet created by a Google form and turns each line into a separate new spreadsheet (basically an invoice). I got that working, now I need to match the strings inside the cells to a price sheet and return the price.
It will do it once, but then on the next item, it does not match. I am using the `===` operator on two arrays. I have `myArray[1].toString()` and no change. I have checked to make sure there is no extra white space. I have checked that the operator is returning `true` when it is working and `false` when it isn't. I am really confused why it isn't working. I have taken the cells I want to match and copied and pasted them into the cell it is supposed to match.

```
  for (j=0; j < invoiceValue.length; j++)//for as many columns as are in the invoice
{
  //Logger.log("In Second Loop J is at " + j + " invoiceValue " + invoiceValue[j]);
  for(k=0; k < priceListArray.length; k++)//compares the invoiceValue array to the priceListarray
  {
    Logger.log("3rd k loop " + k + " invoiceValue is ." + invoiceValue[j] + ". J "+ j + " PRICEARRAY ." + priceListArray[k][0] + ".");
    //the peroids are to check for white space at the beginning or end of the string
    matchCheck = invoiceValue[0][j] === priceListArray[k][0];// I decided to put the out to check if the boolean values where working
    Logger.log("IF loop matching " + matchCheck);

    if(invoiceValue[0][j]=== priceListArray[k][0])
       {  
         //if it matches, it adds the price of the item to the correct cell which so far has worked
         Logger.log("MATCHED " + invoiceValue[0][j]+ " " + j + " priceListA " + priceListArray[k][0] + " K is " + k + " price " +priceListArray[k][1]);
         price = priceListArray[k][1];
         currentInvoice.getRange("C"+(4+j)).setValue(price);//range I need 
         k=priceListArray.length;// once it is matched it is dropped out of loop- no longer checks the rest of the price sheet
        }

  }
```

Here are the logs:

```
[17-05-30 12:03:06:440 EDT] 3rd k loop 0 invoiceValue is .Pastured Michigan Eggs- $3.25 a dozen. J 0 PRICEARRAY .Pastured Michigan Eggs- $3.25 a dozen.  
[17-05-30 12:03:06:440 EDT] IF loop matching true  
[17-05-30 12:03:06:441 EDT] MATCHED Pastured Michigan Eggs- $3.25 a dozen 0 priceListA Pastured Michigan Eggs- $3.25 a dozen K is 0 price 3.25  
[17-05-30 12:03:06:513 EDT] Drop out of J loop 0  
[17-05-30 12:03:06:514 EDT] 3rd k loop 0 invoiceValue is .Fresh Organic Boneless   Skinless Chicken Breast. J 1 PRICEARRAY .Pastured Michigan Eggs- $3.25 a dozen.  
[17-05-30 12:03:06:514 EDT] IF loop matching false  
[17-05-30 12:03:06:515 EDT] 3rd k loop 1 invoiceValue is .Fresh Organic Boneless Skinless Chicken Breast. J 1 PRICEARRAY .Organic, Soy Free Eggs, Pastured, Michigan- $5.75 a dozen.  
[17-05-30 12:03:06:515 EDT] IF loop matching false  
[17-05-30 12:03:06:516 EDT] 3rd k loop 2 invoiceValue is .Fresh Organic Boneless Skinless Chicken Breast. J 1 PRICEARRAY .Pastured Michigan Duck Eggs- $8 a dozen.  
[17-05-30 12:03:06:516 EDT] IF loop matching false  
[17-05-30 12:03:06:517 EDT] 3rd k loop 3 invoiceValue is .Fresh Organic Boneless Skinless Chicken Breast. J 1 PRICEARRAY .Fresh Organic Boneless Skinless Chicken Breast.  
[17-05-30 12:03:06:517 EDT] IF loop matching false  
[17-05-30 12:03:06:518 EDT] 3rd k loop 4 invoiceValue is .Fresh Organic Boneless Skinless Chicken Breast. J 1 PRICEARRAY .Fresh Organic bone less thigh $4.69 lb.
```

So I am not sure what to do, as I said before, I have copied the Fresh Organic Boneless Skinless Chicken Breast cell, into the price list sheet just to make sure they matched exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logger item is referencing `invoiceValue[j]` while your tests are referencing `invoiceValue[0][j]`.  So while the logger entry showing the comparison suggests it should work, you are not comparing that value.  Change the Logger to `invoiceValue[0][j]` and you will see.  Have you used the [Debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) to be able to view your array's values?

Also:
Change this line:

```
k=priceListArray.length;// once it is matched it is dropped out of loop- no longer checks the rest of the price sheet
```

to:

```
break;       // <=== breaks out of the loop early
```

and it will stop the for loop on K once a match is made.

Comment: I will fix that and run it and I did not know about the debugger. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@Karl_S that solved it. I didn't understand the format the array was in:
[invoiceValue picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVvEq.jpg)
 It needed to be `invoiceValue[j][0]`. Thanks